# Moderation analysis hypothesis test

Tags: interaction

I'm working on a moderation analysis where we have two continuous predictors and two similar continuous responses. Our theoretical view is that both predictors should have significant associations (per-specified directions) with the responses as well as their interaction.
My question is, how should I orient the hypothesis testing so that we can have an overall conclusion and not inflate the type I error rate? Most of the moderation analyses I looked at just did single tests of the interaction coefficient but here I'm also curious about the main effects.

My thought was something like this:

1. First do a LRT on the model with main effects only vs full interaction model. If it is significant, add the interaction term.
2. Then test each main effect at alpha = 0.05 and the interaction at alpha = 0.15
3. Apply a multiple testing correction like Bonferroni or controlling the false discovery rate. Not sure how this would work with the alpha levels.
4. Repeat for the second outcome as another hypotheses and ignore type I error accumulation between the two hypotheses.

Any ideas would be lovely. Thanks!